# Emacs OS X: inferior shell $PATH inheritance

Tags: macos, emacs

Emacs manual says the following: `Both M-! and M-| use shell-file-name to specify the shell to use. This variable is initialized based on your SHELL environment variable when Emacs is started. If the file name does not specify a directory, the directories in the list exec-path are searched; this list is initialized based on the environment variable PATH when Emacs is started. Your .emacs file can override either or both of these default initializations.`

`shell-file-name` is set to `/usr/local/bin/zsh`
in terminal, `echo $SHELL` is `usr/local/bin/zsh` and `echo $PATH` is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

However, `M-x ! echo $SHELL` is `/bin/zsh` and `M-x ! echo $PATH` is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

Why is this so? How do I change it to be the same with the terminal $PATH?

Comment: Correction: `M-x ! echo $SHELL` is `/usr/local/bin/zsh`. Also, it looks like the the $PATH shown by `M-x ! echo $PATH` is from `/etc/paths`. I.e. login shell $PATH is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the specifics, but I think what you want is to set `PATH` in your `.emacs`, and that `exec-path` is used to search *for* your shell executable, not used *by* your shell executable.

Basically to put a desired directory at the front of `$PATH`, you want something like:

`(setenv "PATH" (concat my-dir ":" (getenv "PATH")))`

Some guides suggest you also do `(add-to-list 'exec-path my-dir)` when you do this in `.emacs`, I think just to keep the search paths of Emacs and its inferior shells in sync.

But hey, it's been almost a year, hopefully you've found a workaround by now.

Comment: I'm using [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) package, which does - I hope:I did not dive into its codebase - what you're suggesting. Still get the initial behaviour for `M-x ! echo $PATH` - i.e. the path does not get inherited. I mostly gave up on using terminal from within the emacs. My term is `C-z` away nowadays.